# How we can deploy node js application on arm based Eks cluster t4g instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, arm64

I am getting errors while deploying the node js application EKS cluster with the T4g instance.

`standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error`

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
#FROM arm64v8/node:14-buster-slim

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Tested with both base images arm64v8/node:14-buster-slim and node:14 , same error

Comment: I resolved this issue by using buildx tool.  docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t .